# Decimal number respresentation in Restful Web Services

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, decimal

We are developing restful web services for banking operations. The problem is returning decimal numbers. Banking accounts' balance are decimal number and the client of the web service must show this balance in client's localization. So what is the best practice for this problem. Seperation of integer and fractional part is a solution.

For example :

> balanceInt: 1500, balanceFrac:85

rather than sending

> balance:1500.85.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to do following

```
String amt = String.valueOf(1500.85);
String[] strArr = amt.split("\\.");
```

and return `strArr[0]` as main amt and `str[1]` as fraction

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for this. You can get the locale of the client along with webservice request and create a local formatted currency like below. say it is `Swedish`

```
double num = 1234.54;
Locale swedish = new Locale("sv", "SE");
NumberFormat swedishFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(swedish);
return swedishFormat.format(num);
```